# which templating method backboneJS uses?

Tags: backbone.js, javascript, javascript-framework

I've worked with angular which uses DOM-Based templating and also in Ember which uses String-Based templating. But I never worked on backbone. Can anyone tell me which templating method it uses?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone doesn't force you to use any particular templating engine, you can use what you want to render templates.

> Render the UI as you see fit. Backbone is agnostic as to whether you
>   use Underscore templates, Mustache.js, direct DOM manipulation,
>   server-side rendered snippets of HTML, or jQuery UI in your render
>   function. Sometimes you'll create a view for each model ... sometimes
>   you'll have a view that renders thousands of models at once, in a
>   tight loop. Both can be appropriate in the same app, depending on the
>   quantity of data involved, and the complexity of the UI.

(src: http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-tim-toady)

> Backbone is agnostic with respect to your preferred method of HTML
>   templating. Your render function could even munge together an HTML
>   string, or use document.createElement to generate a DOM tree. However,
>   we suggest choosing a nice JavaScript templating library. Mustache.js,
>   Haml-js, and Eco are all fine alternatives. Because Underscore.js is
>   already on the page, _.template is available, and is an excellent
>   choice if you prefer simple interpolated-JavaScript style templates.

(src: http://backbonejs.org/#View-render)

(rtfm!)

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.js is a MV* framework that works with any template system. Typically you will use the Underscore library for creating templates for simple applications. The Underscore library is a dependency of Backbone so its always available to your Backbone.js app.

**A NEW ALTERNATIVE to Underscore.js** has just been released called "Lo-Dash" its sole purpose is to completely replace Underscore.js all together. It also has a template system that you can use in your Backbone.js apps. Simply drop in Lo-Dash, remove underscore and it works seamlessly. When Lo-dash is tested with Backbone.js all the unit tests pass which means that it is a perfect Underscore.js replacement. The Lo-Dash API was also written with performance in mind so it replaces slower clunky JS patterns with better high perf patterns like "for loops" etc... Also it provides like 30 additional features that isn't available with underscore.   **Check it out for yourself:  http://lodash.com/**

After you have checked out Lo-Dash and still need more than i would check out some of the other template systems out there like: Handlebars.js, Mustache.js, Jade, Haml-js, etc...